# NpgsqlException: FATAL: 28000: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry

Tags: npgsql, quartz.net

we've been facing an issue while connecting to Azure PostgreSQL Database from our application when SSL is turned on and TLS set to 1.2. However, we were able to connect to the database successfully when TLS is set to 1.0, which is no longer recommended version. we're facing issue especially when creating or retrieving the Quartz jobs.

Are there any parameters that can be set in the connection string if we're using an older version of the drivers?

we've the below in our application:

- WPF
- Quartz 1.0.3.3
- NHibernate
- Fluent NHibernate
- Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration
- Npgsql 4.1.5

Error:

Failed to obtain DB connection from data source XXXXXX:
Npgsql.NpgsqlException:TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server. Please use a higher TLS version and retry.
Severity: FATAL
Code: 28000

- at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.CheckErrors() at
  Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open() at
  Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection
  Connection) at
  Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnectorInternal(NpgsqlConnection
  Connection) at
  Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection
  Connection) at
  Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NpgsqlConnection
  Connection) at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()

at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.GetConnection()'

Inner Exception:
NpgsqlException: FATAL: 28000: TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server. Please use a higher TLS version and retry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After enabling TLS 1.2 at Postgre server end, we are unable to get the scheduler data from Quartz tables and getting the above error.